# How to stop recursive function?

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'm working on a recursive function and it's the first time I can't figure out how to stop computation.

```
val = [[12, 11, 3, 38], [13, 18, 49, 41], [12, 17, 33, 45], [45, 36, 32, 33]]

def rec(n, o1, o2, o3, o4):
    if n==1: # BECAUSE IN CASE THAT N==1, THERE IS JUST ONE ARGUMENT WITH VALUE 1, OTHER ARGUMENTS SHOULD HAVE VALUE 0
        if o1==1: 
            return val[0][0]
        elif o2==1: 
            return val[0][1]
        elif o3==1:
            return val[0][2]
        else: 
            return val[0][3]

    return max(rec(n - 1, o1 - 1, o2, o3, o4) + val[n][0],
               rec(n - 1, o1, o2 - 1, o3, o4) + val[n][1],
               rec(n - 1, o1, o2, o3 - 1, o4) + val[n][2],
               rec(n - 1, o1, o2, o3, o4 - 1) + val[n][3])
```

It should compute the best distribution into 4 holes. So in each hole there is maximum sum of values. The `val` list tells this: for `val`[0] hole, I can put there 1st item with price `val[0][0]` etc.

The problem is that the `o` values has after few iterations negative numbers which is forbidden.

For example `rec(1,0,0,50,0)` should be 50 because no option left except this.

EDIT:

In fact, what I want is to tell the function that it should not process arguments with value 0.

So `rec(2,0,1,0,1)` should return `max(rec(1,0,0,0,1)+val[2][1], rec(1,0,1,0,0) + val[2][3])`

Comment: That's what I don't get. If n is not 1, I call rec(n-1... ) so it should decrease in each iteration.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean it will ever be EQUAL to 1 ---> change that test to `n < 1` to see

Comment: The problem is that it's integer in my tests.

Comment: See my answer below, it does what you want after your edits. when n is less than 1 it exits. (it never reaches 0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110049/discussion-between-reblochon-masque-and-milano).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to not process recursion a with argument 0, just add a base case for that. What I did was made sure the value returned would cancel out in the revision level above to be 0

```
def rec(n, o1, o2, o3, o4):
    if o1 <= 0:
        return -val[n+1 if n<len(val)-1 else n][0] 
        # checks for out of bounds with inline if,
        # return negative value so compared value in upper level will be 0, 
        # and it will never be chosen
    if o2 <= 0:
        return -val[n+1 if n<len(val)-1 else n][1]
    if o3 <= 0:
        return -val[n+1 if n<len(val)-1 else n][2] 
    if o4 <= 0:
        return -val[n+1 if n<len(val)-1 else n][3] 
    if n<=1: # like Reblochon said, n might be float if you are unlucky
        if o1==1: 
            return val[0][0]
        elif o2==1: 
            return val[0][1]
        elif o3==1:
            return val[0][2]
        else: 
            return val[0][3]

    return max(rec(n - 1, o1 - 1, o2, o3, o4) + val[n][0], \ # you will need these for line continuations
           rec(n - 1, o1, o2 - 1, o3, o4) + val[n][1], \
           rec(n - 1, o1, o2, o3 - 1, o4) + val[n][2], \
           rec(n - 1, o1, o2, o3, o4 - 1) + val[n][3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure it reaches a point when n == 1... In your case here, if n is a float, that may never happen, you would need to test for abs(n - 1) < small epsilon...

Alternatively, and that may be the best solution in this case, you can change the `n == 1` test to `n < 1`; like this:

```
val = [[12, 11, 3, 38], [13, 18, 49, 41], [12, 17, 33, 45], [45, 36, 32, 33]]

def rec(n, o1, o2, o3, o4):
    if n < 1:
        if o1 == 1:
            return val[0][0]
        elif o2 == 1:
            return val[0][1]
        elif o3 == 1:
            return val[0][2]
        else:
            return val[0][3]

    return max(rec(n - 1, o1 - 1, o2, o3, o4) + val[n][0],
               rec(n - 1, o1, o2 - 1, o3, o4) + val[n][1],
               rec(n - 1, o1, o2, o3 - 1, o4) + val[n][2],
               rec(n - 1, o1, o2, o3, o4 - 1) + val[n][3])

rec(3, 2, 2, 2, 2)

>>> 164
```

Comment: The o1-o4 arguments are equal at the beginning. And invariant is that n = sum(o1,o2,o3,o4).

Comment: Yes, it still works with your continuously added conditions... You wanted your recursion to stop... it does now!